# 'Convert' raw SQL to pure Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, thread-safety

I am trying to do a database operation via C# & Entity Framework where I update a counter based on columns in the table, and get back the inserted value.

I need this to be in one line to keep thread safety.

The raw SQL I created works, but I really don't want to leave raw SQL instead of 'clean' EF code. I would appreciate help translating this.

```
int counter = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>($"update [dbo].[table1] set [Counter] = (case when [Counter] < [Maximum] then [Counter] + 1  else [Minimum] end) output inserted.Counter Where Id = {myId}").First();
```

Comment: you can teach yourself using a tutorial - it's really not that hard:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX7_12fwQLU&feature=youtu.be&t=904

Comment: also the documentation these days is really top quality and easy to use:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/

Comment: @johnB Thank you for the response.
 i know how to work with EF and been using it in this project extensively, i am having trouble with this specific query which i did not see an answer for in the video you linked or documentation which i went over already.

Comment: My knowledge of EF is not up to par, but I can give you some general advice. It might simply be impossible to do. EF and SQL were designed/optimized from totally different base Asumptions. There was once a case where due otuside limitations, I **had** to built a query string using String Connaction. It was the only way to get the array for the "IN()" check into it. Luckily the string was not from user input directly, but was filtered through a switch...case block. It did not look pretty, but was perfectly okay.

Comment: FWIW, even this one line isn't thread-safe, because a context isn't.

Comment: Here "thread safe" means that multiple threads can run this code on _different_ DbContext instances, without errors or duplicate counter values returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF LINQ queries are SELECT only.  The only thing you can do without *any* SQL is run queries, save changes to Entities, and scope transactions.  And there's no way to do what you want (at least in SQL Server) without an OUTPUT clause or lock hints.

It's a common misconception that a transaction using [SERIALIZABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) isolation level will work here.  But it won't.  When you read in a SERIALIZABLE transaction you place shared (S) locks on the rows (and ranges) satisfy the query predicates, and hold those locks throughout the transaction.  Since these are shared locks, two SERIALIZABLE transactions can read the same row.  Then if either transaction attempts to convert the shared lock to an exclusive lock to update the row, it will be blocked by the other transaction.  If both attempt an update, a deadlock will occur.

So you *could* put the code in a loop catching and retrying on deadlocks, but that's not really advisable in a high-frequency transaction, and the deadlock will doom your entire transaction, so the loop may need to retry many other statements.  So significantly worse than the UPDATE … OUTPUT pattern used here.

Of course a *much better* pattern is to use a multiple [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) objects instead.  Because even with UPDATE...OUTPUT only one transaction can generate a value at a time, and other sessions will wait until that transaction commits until they can generate a value.  With a SEQUENCE the generation is non-transactional, and multiple sessions can generate values without blocking each others' transactions.

Here the best you can do is wrap that logic in a stored procedure and then call that from a function on your DbContext.

Comment: I think setting serializable isolation level on transaction scope should do the work without explicit lock hints.

Comment: You are right, I did not realize the first lock is shared. Your update was very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure, then call procedure from db_entity with arguments